# Pandas HDFStore : Omitting Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, hdfs, hdf5, hdfstore

I have an HDFStore where i enter data every night. I am wondering if system crash etc, i might rerun processes so I want to make sure that if a row already exists that pandas doesnt include this the next time the process is run. Is there a way to look for duplicates and not include them?

Comment: This is a bit vague,the right way is to post which clearly tells us what process you are running so that we can find you the best solution as per your needs.

Comment: I agree with @SRingne. It would be helpful to know whether you have something similar to "primary key", which helps to __uniquely__ identify each row... Can you post a sample data set (3-5 rows)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a unique index in your HDFStore you can use the following approach:

create sample DF:

```
In [34]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3), columns=list('abc'))

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
          a         b         c
0  0.407144  0.972121  0.462502
1  0.044768  0.165924  0.852705
2  0.703686  0.156382  0.066925
3  0.912794  0.362916  0.866779
4  0.156249  0.625272  0.360799
```

save it to HDFStore:

```
In [36]: store = pd.HDFStore(r'd:/temp/t.h5')

In [37]: store.append('test', df, format='t')
```

Add a new row to our DF:

```
In [38]: df.loc[len(df)] = [-1, -1, -1]

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
          a         b         c
0  0.407144  0.972121  0.462502
1  0.044768  0.165924  0.852705
2  0.703686  0.156382  0.066925
3  0.912794  0.362916  0.866779
4  0.156249  0.625272  0.360799
5 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000   # new row, which is NOT in the HDF file
```

select indices of **duplicated** rows:

```
In [40]: idx = store.select('test', where="index in df.index", columns=['index']).index
```

check:

```
In [41]: df.query("index not in @idx")
Out[41]:
     a    b    c
5 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

append to HDFStore only those rows, which weren't yet saved:

```
In [42]: store.append('test', df.query("index not in @idx"), format='t')
```

check:

```
In [43]: store.select('test')
Out[43]:
          a         b         c
0  0.407144  0.972121  0.462502
1  0.044768  0.165924  0.852705
2  0.703686  0.156382  0.066925
3  0.912794  0.362916  0.866779
4  0.156249  0.625272  0.360799
5 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000   # new row has been added
```

Comment: After trying this solution, It works very well for small (~1GB) HDFstores, but with bigger tables the lookup time for the query `index not in @idx` is too big. This would not be a problem if you want to append data rarely, but in my case, because I "abuse" the HDFstore as if it was a database, the delay is way too much.

Comment: @MakisTsantekidis, IMO this is quite natural - we want to check for duplicates in the index in the whole HDF file. So the bigger HDF file is the longer it will take. Depending on your particular case you may want to check the `max(index)` in the HDF file and compare index values in the DF with that `max_index_value` ...

Comment: good suggestion if the indexes of incoming "records" are sorted. My idea for a speedup in cases that the indexes are not arriving in an orderly fashion is to query once for the existing (duplicate) indexes and keep them in memory, to check the following batch of records against.

Comment: Well, if you can afford to keep all index values from the huge HDF file in memory, then it should work...

Answer (score 0):

if you got a dataframe in your code, you can add the data anyway and apply to it:

```
.drop_duplicates()
```

that will remove any duplicated data from the dataframe.

hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately the data is too large to hold in a dataframe so this approach may not work

Comment: Maybe you can use dask?